# Getting table cell TD value using XPath and DOM in PHP

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I need to access table cell values via DOM / PHP. The web page is loaded into $myHTML. I have identified the XPath as :

```
//*[@id="main-content-inner"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

I want to get the text of the value in the cell as follows:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($myHTML);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    
$myValue = $xpath->query('//*[@id="main-content-inner"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]');

echo $myValue->nodeValue;
```

But I am getting "Undefined Property: DOMNodeList::$nodeValue error. How do I retrieve the value of this table cell? I have tried various techniques from stackoverflow with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMXPath::query() returns a DOMNodeList, even if there's only one match.

If you know for sure you have a match there, you can use

```
echo $myValue->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But if you want to be bullet proof, you better check the length in advance, e.g.

```
if ($myValue->length > 0) {
    echo $myValue->item(0)->nodeValue;
} else {
    //No such cell. What now?
}
```

Comment: looks like my xpath (as reported by chrome) was not accurate..had extra div in it.